# Keep encrypted external hardrive mounted

Tags: mount, hard-drive, 15.04, encryption

I have an external hardrive which is encrypted and I cannot keep it recognized anymore. As soon as I plug it in it is displayed using fdisk -l but after a short while it is not anymore. Then it is again. This makes it impossible to actually mount the device using my encryption facility. the dmesg log shows:

```
[100783.278831] sd 36:0:0:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[100783.278832] sd 36:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[100783.278833] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 f0 00
[100783.278837] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 128
[100783.414610] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[100783.430894] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880077ca9300
[100783.430897] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880077ca9348
[100783.590811] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[100783.607012] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880077ca9300
[100783.607015] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880077ca9348
[100783.746824] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[100783.762993] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880077ca9300
[100783.762995] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880077ca9348
[100784.110404] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[100784.314570] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[100784.515136] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 31, error -71
[100784.627316] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[100784.643670] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880077ca9300
[100784.643673] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880077ca9348
[100784.847600] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[100784.863679] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880077ca9300
[100784.863682] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880077ca9348
```

It seems like it is trying to read from the device and gets confused as it is completely encrypted and thus should not yield any usable data for the OS.

I am using Ubuntu 15.04. Ubuntu 14.04 did not experience such problems. Did my hard drive get corrupted since my last usage or is this a problem introduced with the newer version?